# Android fetch tabhost from context and disabling enabling it

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am trying to fetch TabHost from context. Here is code but it is not working

```
public final static void disableTabs(Context context) {
        TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) ((Activity) context).getParent()
                .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(1).setEnabled(false);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(2).setEnabled(false);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(3).setEnabled(false);
    }
```

and here is how I am calling it.

```
Constants.disableTabs(HomeController.this);
```

Comment: NullPointerException i.e. tabHost variable is null.

Comment: are you sure your tabs are in `Activity` and not inside `ActivityGroup`? because i think Activity self-alone cant show tabs. rite?

Comment: TabHost is present in an activitygroup and activities are being added to the tabhost present in the activitygroup

Comment: so is **HomeController** an `Activity` inside *ActivityGroup* or is it an `ActivityGroup` itself?

Comment: i think if you paste some more reasonable code, then it would be helpful for us to help more

Comment: Thanks you helped my alot in finding solution. Look at the answer of the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution.

Just replace

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) ((Activity) context).getParent()
                .findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost)
```

with

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) ((Activity) context).getParent()
                .findViewById(R.id.tabhost)
```

because my Tabhost was in ActivityGroup and **android.R.id.tabhost** works when we have TabActivity as a parent class so just change it to **R.id.tabhost**.

Comment: good that you figured it out. i believe your **HomeController** is an ActivityGroup. If thats the case, so instead, if you change `Activity` to `ActivityGroup`, it should still work fine and makes more sense